# Inserting variable after pattern using sed

Tags: bash, unix, sed, awk

Hi I try to use Sed in a Bash script and I'm facing a problem. (I'm new to both of them)

I'm trying to insert `$log` after the flag `<!-- Beginning git log -->`.

```
#!/bin/bash
log=`git log -1 --stat --date=short --pretty=format:'[ %cd | %an | %s ]'`
sed "/<!-- Beginning git log -->/a $log" ~/opt/prime.dropbox/commit.md
```

So in commit.md I would have :

```
some text
<!-- Beginning git log -->
git log output
some text
```

I have tried all possible single/double quotes tricks,.. or maybe only all the wrong ones.

This is the error I get most of the time.

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 102: unknown command: `f'
```

I know there should be an easier way with awk, but I'm so close. ^^

Maybe are the Html chars `<!-- -->` blocking or something ?

Thx

Comment: Perhaps the output of `git log` contains characters that are special to sed. What is the value of `$log`?

Comment: [ 2013-08-20 | sergio | git log without -p ]
 index.html |    2 +-
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)
Yes it looks like. But I don't want sed to interpret it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sed is an excellent tool for simple substitutions on a single line, but for anything else, just use awk:

```
awk -v gitlog="$log" '{print} /<!-- Beginning git log -->/{print gitlog}' ~/opt/prime.dropbox/commit.md
```

To run a command in shell and safely over-write the original file with that commands output:

```
the_command orig_file > /usr/tmp/tmp$$ && mv /usr/tmp/tmp$$ orig_file
```

In this case:

```
awk -v gitlog="$log" '{print} /<!-- Beginning git log -->/{print gitlog}' ~/opt/prime.dropbox/commit.md > /usr/tmp/tmp$$ &&
mv /usr/tmp/tmp$$ ~/opt/prime.dropbox/commit.md
```

The temporary file can be in your working directory or in your $HOME or in /usr/tmp or wherever you want and can be named whatever you want.

Comment: ok thanks, but it throws me a "little" error : awk: run time error: cannot command line assign to log
 type clash or keyword
 FILENAME="" FNR=0 NR=0

Comment: Oh gosh. `log` is a reserved variable... Maybe it would work even in sed. Thanks a lot !

Comment: No, that error is coming from awk, it's not related to sed. `log` is the name of an awk function, that's why you can't use it as an awk variable name too. I should have spotted that. I updated my answer.

Comment: I still have a problem with awk, when i run the bash i can see the modifications done in the terminal:exactly what i wanted. But it doesn't save in commit.md. Isn't it supposed to ?

Comment: No, it's not supposed to. If you want the output to go into a file, you need to redirect the output to a file. I'll update my answer to show how to safely modify a file in shell (whether you're running awk or anything else).

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the `!` with `\`:

```
sed "/<\!-- Beginning git log -->/a $log" ~/opt/prime.dropbox/commit.md
```

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to escape `!` inside a script, only when running bash interactively.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

```
$ cat in.txt
some text
<!-- Beginning git log -->
git log output
some text
$ echo $log
[ 2013-08-20 | sergio | git log without -p ] index.html | 2 +- 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-) Yes it looks like.
$ sed "/<\!-- Beginning git log -->/a $log"  in.txt
some text
<!-- Beginning git log -->
[ 2013-08-20 | sergio | git log without -p ] index.html | 2 +- 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-) Yes it looks like.
git log output
some text
```

Comment: Lol, yeah it works when I directly type the output of `git log` and not $log.. so ... WTF !

Answer (score 0):

Ran into a similar issue to yours and the following worked for me.

Initialized your log variable and commit.md with sample data:

```
$ log=`git log -1 --stat --date=short --pretty=format:'[ %cd | %an | %s ]'`
$ echo "$log"
[ 2021-02-19 | My Test | docs: update light-baseimage links ]
 image/Dockerfile                             | 6 +++---
 image/service/test/schema.sh                | 2 +-
 image/service/test/process.sh               | 2 +-
 image/service/test/startup.sh               | 4 ++--
 4 files changed, 7 insertions(+), 7 deletions(-)
$ cat commit.md 
some text
<!-- Beginning git log -->
git log output
some text
```

I couldn't get the sed "a" (append text) command to work on a reasonable sed one liner because it would not escape the newline on a variable. So multi-line string variables would be end up as one long line with a space replacing the newline.  Example:

```
$ sed '/<!-- Beginning git log -->/a '"$(echo $log)"'' commit.md
some text
<!-- Beginning git log -->
[ 2021-02-19 | My Test | docs: update light-baseimage links ] image/Dockerfile | 6 +++--- image/service/test/schema.sh | 2 +- image/service/test/process.sh | 2 +- image/service/test/startup.sh | 4 ++-- 4 files changed, 7 insertions(+), 7 deletions(-)
git log output
some text
```

But I was able to use the sed "r" (append text read from filename) command and treat the variable like a file.  This way a multi-line string variable prints newlines correctly.

Solution:

```
$ sed '/<!-- Beginning git log -->/r /dev/stdin' commit.md <<< "$log"
```

This outputs:

```
some text
<!-- Beginning git log -->
[ 2021-02-19 | My Test | docs: update light-baseimage links ]
 image/Dockerfile                             | 6 +++---
 image/service/test/schema.sh                | 2 +-
 image/service/test/process.sh               | 2 +-
 image/service/test/startup.sh               | 4 ++--
 4 files changed, 7 insertions(+), 7 deletions(-)
git log output
some text
```

Or if you would like the change in place on commit.md, add `-i` flag to sed like this:

```
$ sed -i '/<!-- Beginning git log -->/r /dev/stdin' commit.md <<< "$log"
```

Output:

```
$ cat commit.md 
some text
<!-- Beginning git log -->
[ 2021-02-19 | My Test | docs: update light-baseimage links ]
 image/Dockerfile                             | 6 +++---
 image/service/test/schema.sh                | 2 +-
 image/service/test/process.sh               | 2 +-
 image/service/test/startup.sh               | 4 ++--
 4 files changed, 7 insertions(+), 7 deletions(-)
git log output
some text
```